# How to change ID in Select2 ajax script function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I got some trouble with select2 ajax script, My unique_ID in table field is called "no", so I Unable to select an item in Select2 drop down.
When I changed my database table field "no_donatur" into "ID" my ajax select2 is working..

here is my function script :

```
$('.muzakki').select2({
    placeholder: '--- Select Item ---',
    ajax: {
        url: '<?php echo site_url("transaksi/penerimaan_ajax") ?>',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        cache: true,
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        }
    }
});
```

And also here is some json output :

```
[{"no":"4150","text":"NASIKIN (SMP N 2 MANYARAN)"},{"no":"5818","text":"Winasih (Via Asgim)"},{"no":"7499","text":"Tri winasih (Via Yeti)"},{"no":"9206","text":"RINASIH (RS ORTHOPEDI)"},{"no":"11673","text":"SHOLEH (NASI KABULI)"},{"no":"12818","text":"ININGSIH (BADAN PERTAHANAN NASIONAL)"},{"no":"20504","text":"NASITA GAIDA MUTIE (MOJOLABAN)"},{"no":"23656","text":"NASIR (PUSK NGAWEN)"},{"no":"26520","text":"RISMA AZIL NASIFA "},{"no":"26549","text":"SRI KARNASI"}]
```

How can I change "no" into ID without changing my database structure ?

Answer (score 0):

solved by renaming no as id in my model..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please done with it in model like,

```
SELECT no AS ID,....,.. FROM table_name
```